# FormData upload in angular4 application

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

In my angular4 application I'm trying to upload the video to server.
But no matter what i add to the content type it always results in error from the server.
In angular 1 the same api is hit using **{ 'Content-Type': undefined }**

i tried the same in angular but it dint work.
The data and everything is correct.
I have tried with content-type set as below

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Authorization', token);
headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
```

and also as below

**headers.append('Content-Type', undefined);**

below is the http request method:

```
public uploadVideo(formData: any) {


        var Upload = this.baseUrl + this.ngAuth.getApiUrl('Upload');
        var authData = JSON.parse(this.localStorage.localStorageGet('token'));
        var token = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        var self = this;

        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
        headers.append('Authorization', token);
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return this.http.post(Upload , formData, { headers: headers, method: 'POST' })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());

    }
```

Please guide!
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So after going through a lot of solution i stumbled upon this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11819)

It says do not add the Content-Type to the header.
So from my request header i removed

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. For others I can add that if you already have the `Content-Type` header being set by Angular (my issue), you can do `headers: myHeaders.delete('Content-Type')`

Answer (score 4):

I'll give a reference with Angular 6 and Spring Boot.

**Angular 6 :**

```js
onSubmit(){
const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
console.log(this.currentFileUpload)
formdata.append('uploadedFile', this.currentFileUpload);
formdata.append('description',"My Desc");
formdata.append('companyName',"ABC")
formdata.append('numberOfRecords',"2")
console.log(formdata.get('uploadedFile'))

this.asyncService.makeUploadRequest('file/upload',formdata).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response)
  if(response.responseCode == '00'){
    console.log('Successfully uploaded')
  }
  else {
    console.log("error")
  }
 });
}


makeUploadRequest(method, body) : Observable<any> {
    const url = "http://localhost:8097" + "/" + method;

    const headers = new Headers();
    this.token="Bearer"+" "+localStorage.getItem('token'); 
    headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
    // No need to set 'content type'
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.post(url, body, options).pipe(
        map((response : Response) => {
            var json = response.json();                
         return json; 
        })
    );
}
```

**Spring Boot API :**

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { "/file" })
public class FileController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response uploadFile(@RequestParam("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFileRef){
        System.out.println(uploadedFileRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: What Content-Type is Angular 6 setting for you? In my case it's application/json and I don't think that's right...

Comment: The content-type in my case is multipart/form-data when not specified in header : Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytKcUBulaQJNwYb6P